# Gunicorn paste option

Tags: python, gunicorn

I'm trying to start gunicorn with `--paste` option using this [documentation](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/run.html#paste-deployment)

But when I run command `gunicorn --paste develop.ini -b :8083`, I got such error

```
Error: No module named 'paste'
```

How can this be fixed?

Comment: Did you install [Paste](https://pypi.org/project/Paste/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have the module installed or it is not installed correctly when you run the command. That is pretty much the only reason you ever get " Error: No module named 'xyz' ".

I would double check path/file folders etc., and/or make sure it is installed correctly.